# Java Layering Images

Tags: java, image, background

I'm trying to set a backdrop image then have things go on top of that backdrop image but the problem I'm running into is that the backdrop is layering over everything else. I'm hoping someone can show me how to layer images properly.

The code I have so far for painting the background is this,

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    DoAnimation();
    if (bInGame) {
        PlayGame(g2d);
    } else {
        ShowIntroScreen(g2d);
    }
    g.drawImage(ii, 5, 5, this);
    //g.drawImage(Background, 0, 0, null);
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
    g.dispose();
}
```

The g.drawImage that has Background in when active will be the only thing that appears but when I comment it out everything else shows up again.  I've tried putting my background into a separate file in hopes that it will just put it behind everything else

Comment: What does your code look like so far?

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'm about 85% sure that makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to draw the background image first. In your code snippet you draw it last.

i.e.

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

    // assuming you want it behind everything else
    // drawn to g2d after this point
    g.drawImage(Background, 0, 0, null);

    DoAnimation();
    if (bInGame) {
        PlayGame(g2d);
    } else {
        ShowIntroScreen(g2d);
    }
    g.drawImage(ii, 5, 5, this);
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
    g.dispose();
}
```

Think of drawing to a Graphics context as piling up sheets of paper. Each draw call goes over what is done before it. When you draw a new image, it covers whatever was there before.

Comment: I could have sworn that I had tried that already but when I tried again after your suggestion it finally worked, thank you so much!

Comment: So How can you do this with images. Lets say I have a bunch of cards and I would like to layer one over another with a horizontal offset of around 50px between them. Here's the complete discussion thread. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32218170/stack-cards-horizontally-with-some-offset