# Stack Cards horizontally with some offset

Tags: java, swing

How do I stack images (of cards) like this:

[image]

This is what I have so far and obviously I am trying to set the location of the JLabel cardIcon which gets replaced each time I guess.

```
    JPanel tableMat = new JPanel();

            for (CardSet card : playersHand) {

                String path = dirPath + card.suit().toString()+"-"+card.rank().toString()+".gif";
                File file = new File(path);

                if (!file.exists()) {
                    System.out.println(path);
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("file " + file + " does not exist");


                } else {
                    BufferedImage icon = ImageIO.read(new File(file.getAbsolutePath()));
                    JLabel cardIcon = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(icon));
                    cardIcon.setLocation(300,300);
                    tableMat.add(cardIcon);

                }

            }
```

Comment: From a glance, it looks like cardIcon.setLocation() is setting all of your cards to the same location.

Comment: Actually its not even doing that. All it does right now is starts laying cards from position 0,0 and one after another just like a flow layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing like this and it works well for me.

```
    JLayeredPane tableMat = new JLayeredPane();
        int i =0;
        int x_offset = 15;
        for (CardSet card : playersHand) {

            String path = dirPath + card.suit().toString()+"-"+card.rank().toString()+".gif";
            File file = new File(path);

            if (!file.exists()) {
                System.out.println(path);
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("file " + file + " does not exist");


            } else {
                BufferedImage icon = ImageIO.read(new File(file.getAbsolutePath()));
                JLabel cardIcon = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(icon));
                cardIcon.setBounds(x_offset,20,300,300);
                tableMat.add(cardIcon, new Integer(i));
                i++;
                x_offset += 15;

            }

        }
```

And hence the output is :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`tableMat = new JPanel()` initialises it with the default FlowLayout, so `cardIcon.setLocation(300, 300)` will be ignored - the layout manager will decide the position when `tableMat.add(cardIcon)` is called.

You need to remove the layout manager from tableMat, e.g. `tableMat = new JPanel(null)`.

Of course, you also need to update the x co-ordinate to stagger them left-to-right.
See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html